# Foreign key not null default value for undirectional ManyToOne association

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, constraints

Consider I have a table:

```
create table product(id int8 not null, ... , primary key (id));
```

I have inserted some records, so 'product' is not empty.

Then I need another table:

```
create table order(id int8 not null, ..., primary key (id))
```

After that I decided to add connection between 'product' and 'order', in Order entity added:

```
@NotNull
@ManyToOne
private Product product;
```

So in sql I do following:

```
alter table order add column product int8 not null default (???);
alter table order add constraint FK_order_product foreign key (product) references product;
```

What should I write at (???)?
If I set default to 0, then SQL will expectedly complain like:
(Key product(0)) is not in the 'product' table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `order` table is also not empty (if the table is empty it works fine). In your case I recommend you to add the field by executing

```
alter table order add column product int8 not null default 0;
```

then alter each row of the `order` table to make the correct references to the `product` table in the `product` field and finally add the `Foreign Key` constraint.

Also if your `order` table is populated with test data, you may just truncate it before executing your script, and you can use any default in this case or not use it at all.